# HttpWebRequest to Automate Secure Requests

Tags: c#, wpf, httpwebrequest, fiddler, webautomation

I have done web automations in the past where I use fiddler and recreate the requests in C#.  The website I'm currently working on automating doesn't have any viewable POST or GET requests in fiddler.  Everything is either listed as secure or simply labeled "Tunnel To" is there a way to figure out what those requests are and replicate them?  Or is my best bet to simply use a webBrowser control and automate it that way?

I'd prefer to use HttpWebRequests or something similar if possible because of the speed and security, but I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking about HTTPS requests which Fiddler doesn't decrypt by default. To allow decruption, go to Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS and ensure the *Capture HTTPS CONNECTs *and *Decrypt HTTPS traffic* checkboxes are selected

Comment: Looking at the request that the site generated, it is of course an encrypted cookie.  Simply looking at the request and replacing some text with the login username and password is not possible.  Is there a good way to break down this request?